# How to merge all the lines into single line in BBEDIT

Tags: edit, bbedit

How can I merge all the lines into single line by using BBEdit (MAC)

Example:

```
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

Expected output:

```
Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Remove Line Breaks" command on the Text menu will accomplish this.

Comment: Thank you. I often get XML broken into 80-byte chunks. This command would get it onelined and then a XML parser could cope with it.

Comment: "Remove Line Breaks" command will replace line breaks with single space character. If you really want to remove line breaks without spaces you can use grep in the find menu. Find "\n" and replace with nothing.

Comment: Hey... Siegel... on a BBEdit question. Seems like I've heard that name in a similar context before. 